# error warning symbol while creating project

Tags: java, eclipse

while creating a project in eclipse it shows red colored exclamation symbol and on the class giving this error:

> 'Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor'

Comment: show us the affected code (and super class code).

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when your built path is not configured correctly:

In eclipse to remove this error right click on your project:

> Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries tag > Add Library > JRE System Library > Select Alternate JRE > select JRE that is installed in your system > Finish

In Java each class required object (base of all class) which is not defined in this case due to wrong path, so it throwing this particular error.

Comment: Exactly!!! and each class extends Objects which is not included if path is not correct.

Comment: even when the JRE is correctly set this error might occurs (mistake in the code), that was my point

Comment: The error message is just misleading, Eclipse is not very intelligent, and @RC. - Object has just one empty constructor so this error can _never_ happen

Comment: @RC. true but as OP said he is creating new project, so in this case I think no new code is there to cause error.